# Using static variables in C++

Tags: c++, variables, static, undefined-symbol

I have a class, which is not owned by any other classes, therefore accessed via static methods such as `addKeyword()`:

```
class Foo {

  public:

   /* other public methods and such */

    static void addKeyword(Keyword& keyword);

  private:

    static Foo a;

    std::vector<Keyword> keywords;

    /* Foo's private variables and methods */

    void addKeywordToObject(Keyword& keyword);

}
```

The idea of doing it like this is I can then call:

```
//called from elsewhere in the program
void Foo::addKeyword(Keyword& keyword){
  a.addKeywordToObject(keyword);
}

//called from addKeyword() above
void Foo::addKeywordToObject(Keyword& keyword){
  this->keywords.push_back(keyword);
}
```

And the keyword is added to a's vector of keywords.

However - and I'm sure there's something I'm doing fundamentally wrongly - when I try and compile this code, I get the linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "Namespace::Foo::a", referenced from:
Namespace::Foo::addKeyword(Namespace::Keyword) in Foo.o.
```

I have a feeling it's because I'm using the static variable wrongly, but I'm not sure how or why. Could anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `static` member in an implementation file.

```
Foo Foo::a;
```

Comment: That worked! Can you tell me why that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

Static data members, are treated as global variables by the compiler, and reside in the data segment as such (only name-wise they are in the class namespace and follow the public/private rules of the class).
The declaration of a static data member in a class is similar to *extern* for global variables. It tells the compiler that such a variable exists in some translation unit. For the final symbol resolution, the linker needs to actually find the declaration of the variable in some translation unit.